# How to resize multiple Drawables and update their bounds in a fast, consistent manner

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, 2d-games

I have a problem with my implementation of a hexagonal grid based game. Because the game requires a 91-cell hex board, like my simple board below, I wanted the user to be able to scale the board with zoom/pinch, and move it around with panning. However, none of my implementations of scaling and moving allow me to simultaneously have:

1) Consistent bounds, allowing me to be able to drag and drop pieces onto the Drawables that make up each cell.

2) Consistent relative positioning, allowing the cells to remain next to each other in the same configuration below.

3) Smooth scaling and panning, allowing the game to run quickly and have a zoom/pinch experience similar to that of other apps.

[image: A 91-cell hex board]

Some things I've tried (All being done using an Activity -> SurfaceView -> Thread, like in the LunarLander example) :

1. Drawing to a bitmap, scaling the bitmap with a matrix, translating the canvas. Handles points 2 and 3, but I can't figure out how to keep the bounds of the cell consistent. A HexCell is a class that holds a Drawable of a single cell, and the two dimensional array, board, contains HexCells.

   ```
   public void drawBoard(Canvas c, int posX, int posY, float scaleFactor, float pivotPointX, float pivotPointY, boolean firstDraw) {
       for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < board.get(i).size(); j++) {
               board.get(i).get(j).draw(bitmapCanvas);
           }
       }
       if(firstDraw) {
           int width = bitmap.getWidth();
           int height = bitmap.getHeight();
           float scale;
           if(canvasWidth < canvasHeight) {
               scale = ((float) canvasWidth) / width;
           }
           else {
               scale = ((float) canvasHeight) / height;
           }
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

           // Resize the bit map
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

           // Recreate the new Bitmap
           bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
           c.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
       }
       c.save();
       c.translate(posX, posY);
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
       c.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
       c.restore();
   }
   ```
2. Modifying the bounds of the Drawable using a Matrix. This updates the bounds for point 1, and with some tweaking I think I could get 2 and 3 but I'm unsure how to make the scaling stop being "sticky", meaning not as smooth as the first method. In addition, when scaling the cells by a large amount, some of them become different sizes and start moving out of position relative to the other cells.

   ```
   public void drawBoard(Canvas c, int posX, int posY, float scaleFactor, float pivotPointX, float pivotPointY, boolean firstDraw) {
       for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < board.get(i).size(); j++) {
               Rect bounds = board.get(i).get(j).getBounds();
               RectF boundsF = new RectF(bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.right, bounds.bottom);
               matrix.mapRect(boundsF);
               bounds = new Rect((int)boundsF.left, (int)boundsF.top, (int)boundsF.right, (int)boundsF.bottom);
               board.get(i).get(j).setBounds(bounds);
               board.get(i).get(j).draw(c);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Directly modifying the bounds of the Drawable. This updates the bounds for point 1, but lacks in points 2 and 3. In addition, because I'm not using the matrix postScale with pivotPoints, the cells stay centered where they are and become smaller/larger without moving to stay next to each other.

   ```
   public void resize(int dx, int dy, float scaleFactor) {
       xPos += dx;
       yPos += dy;
       width *= scaleFactor;
       height *= scaleFactor;
       cell.setBounds(xPos, yPos, xPos + width, yPos + height);
   }
   ```

What should I do? How can I update bounds while scaling and moving so that I can eventually place pieces on the board? Should I scrap my desire for scaling and panning, and instead use a GridView or something like that to implement the board?

---

Edit:

Working on this some more, I've determined that option 1 is the best way to go. It is much faster, and keeps the cells in a consistent formation. I found out that if you invert the transformation applied to the canvas and apply that to the coordinates from a touch event, you can get back to the original bounds of the cells, and therefore select them appropriately.

However, I'm having trouble accurately inverting the transformation.

```
x /= scaleFactor;
y /= scaleFactor;
x -= posX + pivotPointX;
y -= posY + pivotPointY;
```

is not a working inversion of:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(posX, posY);
canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
```

Does anyone know how to invert it appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the drawBoard() method I did:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(posX, posY);
canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
canvas.getMatrix(canvasMatrix); // Save the matrix that has the transformations so we can invert it
for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < board.get(i).size(); j++) {
         board.get(i).get(j).draw(c);
    }
}
canvas.restore();
```

In the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) method in the View I did:

```
float x = ev.getX();
float y = ev.getY();

float[] pts = {x, y};
Matrix canvasMatrix = boardThread.getCanvasMatrix(); // get the matrix with the transformations
Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
canvasMatrix.invert(invertMatrix); // invert the matrix
invertMatrix.mapPoints(pts); // map the inversion to the points x and y
boardThread.selectHex((int)pts[0], (int)pts[1]);
```

This does the trick! Now if anyone has any suggestions to avoid using the deprecated canvas.getMatrix() method, that would be great :)